# Autosizing WinForms Dialog to fit inner content

Tags: winforms, modal-dialog

I'm writing a kind of "generic container dialog", which will ensure that all modal dialogs in an app will have the exact same "chrome" (namely, buttons, icons, etc.). I came up with the following:

[image]

The `containerPanel` is just a `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`.

Now what I want is as follows: for each dialog in an app, I want to create a separate `UserControl` (not a full-blown `Form`) and then "host" it inside this generic dialog. To do so, I need to somehow make this dialog self-adjustable so that it would shrink or grow depending on the size of a control hosted inside it.

How can I do that? Do I need some kind of layout control, or is there some special magical property to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an boolean autosize property for windows.form.control . When true it allows the control to autosize automatically to fit its contents

Comment: This is also true for Windows.Form . It also has the AutoSize property which allows it to shrink and grow according to contents.

Comment: I would also suggest using the proper anchors on the panel and buttons in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through `Controls` collection and look for lower-bottom corner of every control that is enumerated, find maximum x and maximum y, and set form (container) Width and Height appropriately.